# Gparted : How can I merge unallocated space to my Ubuntu?

Tags: 14.04, dual-boot, partitioning, gparted

It was my initial status, so I wanted to reduce Windows 10 storage (`dev/sda3`) and merge that unallocated space to my Ubuntu

There are unallocated space left to Ubuntu space.

But when I try to expand Ubuntu storage to left side, it fails.

How can I solve this?

[image: Screenshot 1]
[image: Screenshot 2]

Comment: you can't change the partition size of the partition you're currently working on, try **Gparted** Live it'll work, or wait for other people to comment

Answer (score 1):

You can't change the size of a partition you're currently in.

To change that - you need to use some external file system.

There are many sources in which you can find answers regarding partitioning:

- https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PartitioningSchemes
- https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DiskSpace

including this site:

- [How to resize partitions?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/126153/how-to-resize-partitions)

personally, I'd advise you to make a USB stick, and use a live OS's partitioning software to make those changes. You can find more information on that here:

- https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/FromUSBStickQuick